# how to wrtite a batch file that can copy a file or entire folder to the given destination?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, copy-paste, robocopy

I am totally new to batch scripting in windows. I am trying to write a script thats function would be drag and dropping any file or folder to the batch and a command prompt window would appear for typing in the destination's path and the copying method would be Robocopy.

Here is where I got:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "%~1"  
SET /P _inputname = "Copy to:"
IF "%_inputname%" = "%CD%"
(
start robocopy.exe robocopy "%~1" "%_inputname%"
)
```

The command prompt window appears with the files name on the top, I can type the path...
But after pressing enter, the window disappears and nothing happens.
I know this code has some issues but thats why I am posting :)

Thank You in advance for the answers!

Comment: Being new to batch scripting, and stack overflow, I recommend searching for questions / answers prior to asking questions. I also recommend typing `help /?`,`robocopy /?`,`For /?` in `cmd.exe` and familiarising yourself with the commands.

Comment: Your provided code is invalid, your opening parenthesis should be on the same line as the `IF` command, `IF "%_inputname%" = "%CD%" (`. I would also advise that you open up a Command Prompt window, enter `if /?` to read its help information. From that you'll note that your syntax for the command is incorrect. My advice would be to use `IF /I "%_inputname%"=="%CD%" (`. Please note however, that you have not specified a current directory, so at this time it is not possible for me to determine whether `%CD%` is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I will use your advices! I searched many questions @T3RR0R